# group by month and year parts using queryover

Tags: c#, nhibernate, group-by, queryover

I have a model, that contains a DateTime field and a Price field.
I want to get a list that gives me an aggregation of month/year - price
so for the data:

1. 15/01/2012 200
2. 16/01/2012 200
3. 15/02/2012 300
4. 16/02/2012 300
5. 15/03/2012 400
6. 16/03/2012 400

I will get:

1. 01/2012 400
2. 02/2012 600
3. 03/2012 800

So far I didn't find a way to achive this using QueryOver.
I keep getting "could not resolve property" when i try to look at the Month/Year parts of the date.

Those questions:

[Group posts by year, then by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380844/group-posts-by-year-then-by-month)

[Group/Sort by Date Year/Month, Partial Select with NHibernate (Projection? Transformation?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377563/group-sort-by-date-year-month-partial-select-with-nhibernate-projection-trans)

got answered using LINQ - not what I'm looking for.

Any ideas?
Thanks

(using NHibernate 3.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QueryOver is not a good choice because grouping will need to be done using a SQL expression. For this type of query, QueryOver is simply a pointless abstraction that adds no value.

If you must do it using QueryOver you could do something like:

```
session.QueryOver<...>()
   .SelectList(list => list
      .Select(GroupProperty(Projections.SqlProjection(...)))
      .SelectSum(x => x.Price)
   );
```

Comment: In Criteria you will have to use the same projection... that's what i hoped to get around, so what do you recommend if not the QueryOver?

Comment: Probably just use ICriteria. Or you could map a SQL query similar to the idea explained here: http://ayende.com/blog/3948/nhibernate-mapping-named-queries-query-and-sql-query. If you want to keep magic strings and database specific code in a single location then the latter would be the way to go.